# App Open Ad Admob @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START) deprecated

Tags: admob

this is the example We are following

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open

In App Open Ad Admob @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START) is used however it is deprecated . what is the alternative that we can use and how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

delete this code

```
  /** LifecycleObserver method that shows the app open ad when the app moves to foreground. */
//  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
//  fun onMoveToForeground() {
//    // Show the ad (if available) when the app moves to foreground.
//    currentActivity?.let {
//      appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(it)
//    }
//  }
```

and write

```
  private lateinit var diff: DefaultLifecycleObserver

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
    MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
    diff = object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
      override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onStart(owner)
        currentActivity?.let {
          appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(it)
        }
      }
    }
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(diff)
    appOpenAdManager = AppOpenAdManager()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved the problem.

```
private val lifecycleEventObserver = LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
    if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_START) {
        showAdIfAvailable()
    }
}
```

And then you can add what you declared as an observer like this.

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleEventObserver)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. add this to your build.gradle, dependencies:

> ```
> implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
> ```

2. Create a new class e.g. MyLifecycleObserver which implements the interface "DefaultLifecycleObserver", then override onCreate, onResume, and ...

> ```
> class MyLifecycleObserver: DefaultLifecycleObserver {
>     override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
>         super.onCreate(owner)
>         Log.i("lifecycleEvents", "onCreate")
>     }
>     override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
>         super.onResume(owner)
>         Log.i("lifecycleEvents","onResume")
>     }
> }
> ```

3. In your MainActivity, just call lifecycle.addObserver() and pass an instance of MyLifecycleObserver class.

> ```
> lifecycle.addObserver(MyLifecycleObserver())
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should implementation this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
}
```

Then, you should write this:

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleEventObserver)

    }
```

And last, you should write this:

```
var lifecycleEventObserver = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> {
                //your code here
            }
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> {
                //your code here
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }
```

Detailed code implementation you can read from this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271549/lifecycle-onlifecycleevent-is-deprecated-and-you-should-use-lifecycleeventob)