# Lifecycle @OnLifecycleEvent() is deprecated, and you should use LifecycleEventObserver or DefaultLifecycleObserver

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, lifecycle, application-lifecycle

##### Answer is on bottom

I think it will be useful for you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 1 - LifecycleEventObserver

#### Firstly

You should implementation this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
}
```

#### Secondly

You should write this:

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleEventObserver)

    }
```

#### Thirdly

You should write this:

In here I implemented only two Lifecycle Event, when you need other Lifecycle Event, you should implement them

```
    var lifecycleEventObserver = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> {
                //your code here
            }
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> {
                //your code here
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }
```

### 2 - DefaultLifecycleObserver

#### Firstly

You should implementation this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
}
```

#### Secondly

You should write this:

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(defaultLifecycleObserver)

    }
```

#### Thirdly

You should write this:

In here I implemented only two Lifecycle Event, when you need other Lifecycle Event, you should implement them

```
    var defaultLifecycleObserver = object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {

        override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            super.onStart(owner)
            //your code here
        }

        override fun onStop(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            super.onStop(owner)
            //your code here
        }
    }
```

### 3 - ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

#### Firstly

You should write this:

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(activityLifecycleCallbacks)

    }
```

#### Secondly

You should write this:

```
    private val activityLifecycleCallbacks = object : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        
        override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            
        }

        override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
            
        }

        override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
            
        }

        override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
           
        }

        override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {
            
        }

        override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {

        }

        override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {

        }

    }
```